# Delegation token in identityserver4

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have this client flow:
1.client1 calling api1
2.api1 calling api2

I need the identity from the client 1 will pass to api2
I implemented DelegationTokenGrantValidator using IExtensionGrantValidator

I sent the original client1 token using
Parameters = new Dictionary { { "token", token } }

I followed this guide:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant

I abling to generate token in api1 and call api2 but the identity is api1 and not client1

Comment: There is no problem with delegation, what you describe is the documented behaviour. Seems you don't need delegation at all. Just let client1 call api2 and the problem is solved.

Comment: no, you get me wrong. i cant client1 will call api2, the flow i describe is a given flow and cant be changed.
how can i pass the client1 identity through all hierarchy calls?

Comment: Client1 is not the identity, the user is the identity. Delegation is about calling a back end API _on behalf of the interactive user_. The clientId is not relevant. Do you have an interactive user? What flow are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the identity data in your `ValidateAsync` method of your custom grant:

```
public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
{
    var userToken = context.Request.Raw.Get("token");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userToken))
    {
    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
    return;
    }

    var result = await _validator.ValidateAccessTokenAsync(userToken);
    if (result.IsError)
    {
        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
        return;
    }

    var sub = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject)?.Value;
    var username = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
    var other = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "other")?.Value;
    // ...

    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, sub));
    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, username));
    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, other));
    // ...

    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(subject: sub, authenticationMethod: GrantType, claims: claims);
    return;
}
```